# HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException:

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm getting this exception when  I try to show databases.

```
vallabh@vallabh:~$ hive


hive> show databases;
```

FAILED: HiveException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.SessionHiveMetaStoreClient

Following is my .bashrc file

```
# Set HIVE_HOME
export HIVE_HOME=/opt/apache-hive-3.0.0-bin
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/opt/apache-hive-3.0.0-bin/conf/
export PATH=$PATH:$HIVE_HOME/bin
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/hadoop-3.0.1/lib/*:.
export CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH:/opt/apache-hive-3.0.0-bin/lib/*:
```

following is my hive-env.sh file

```
# Set HADOOP_HOME to point to a specific hadoop install directory
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.0.1
# Hive Configuration Directory can be controlled by:
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=/opt/apache-hive-3.0.0-bin/conf
```

following is my hive-config.sh file

```
export HADOOP_HOME=/opt/hadoop-3.0.1
```

following is my hive-site.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="confguration.xsl"?><!--
Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
contri utor license agreements. See the NOTICE fle distri uted with
this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
The ASF licenses this fle to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
(the "License"); you may not use this fle except in compliance with
the License. You may o tain a copy of the License at
http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
Unless required y applica le law or agreed to in writing, software-->




<confguration>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
<value>jd c:mysql://localhost/metastore?createDatabaseIfNotExist=true</value>
<description>
JDBC connect string for a JDBC metastore.
To use SSL to encrypt/authenticate the connection, provide data ase-specifc SSL fag in
the connection URL.
For example, jd c:postgresql://myhost/d ?ssl=true for postgres database.
</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>

<value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
<description>Driver class name for a JDBC metastore</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionUserName</name>
<value>hiveuser</value>
<description>Username to use against metastore database</description>
</property>



<property>
<name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionPassword</name>
<value>password@123</value>
<description>password to use against metastore database</description>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateSchema</name>
<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.fxedDatastore</name>


<value>true</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>datanucleus.autoCreateTables</name>
<value>True</value>
</property>
</confguration>
```

What will be the possible cause of the error.?

Comment: You need to verify the metastore actually started before running Hive CLI. For starters, jdbc... You're missing the B in the xml

Comment: Can you please explain how to do that?

Comment: can you please share your error log of hive?

Comment: Running `jps` or `ps` commands should show the metastore process